# Java Runnable threads stuck in native methods, consuming high CPU for a long time

Tags: java, cpu, native-code

Hi i have a case where a bunch of same thread are in RUNNABLE state executing a Native method and  stuck in it for a long time (more than an Hour)

```
"http-bio-8080-exec-806" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fd4b0174800 nid=0x7e09 runnable [0x00007fd84a141000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getSuperclass(Native Method)

"http-bio-8080-exec-795" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fce6c007800 nid=0x7e01 runnable [0x00007fd3f037a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getSuperclass(Native Method)

"http-bio-8080-exec-802" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fd67c11a000 nid=0x7dff runnable [0x00007fd4723b1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getSuperclass(Native Method)

"http-bio-8080-exec-800" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fd67c2a8000 nid=0x7dfe runnable [0x00007fd7f2dfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getSuperclass(Native Method)

"http-bio-8080-exec-783" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fcd68001800 nid=0x7699 runnable [0x00007fd2b05fd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getSuperclass(Native Method)

"http-bio-8080-exec-612" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fd53001b000 nid=0x55a9 runnable [0x00007fd5013cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE 
    at java.lang.Class.getSuperclass(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(EqualsBuilder.java:286)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(EqualsBuilder.java:124)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.data.FakeBarChartEntry.equals(FakeBarChartEntry.java:44)
    at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(Unknown Source)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.data.BarChartDataSorter.currentIsPriorToBuffer(BarChartDataSorter.java:121)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.data.BarChartDataSorter.sortEntriesAndFillGaps(BarChartDataSorter.java:98)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.data.BarChartDataSorter.sortAndEnrichChartData(BarChartDataSorter.java:27)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.data.BarChartDataCollector.collectChartData(BarChartDataCollector.java:54)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.BarChartGadget.createRestClass(BarChartGadget.java:111)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.BarChartGadget.getVersionsForProject(BarChartGadget.java:85)
    at com.tngtech.jira.plugins.gadget.BarChartGadget.getVersionsForProject(BarChartGadget.java:67)
```

I just can't get whats going on here ? after an hour the threads terminate!

Comment: Can you add code of `FakeBarChartEntry` ?

Comment: You or something you're  using appears to have written an `equals()` method that uses reflection. This is a seriously bad idea.

Comment: Having lots of threads within one method doesn’t necessary imply that there is a multi-threading issue (*Especially* if all threads are reported to be `RUNNABLE`). It might just be the case that the method is invoked quite often. In your stack trace I see things like “chart data” (potentially lots of items), a sorting operation which invokes methods like `ArrayList.indexOf` which invokes a Reflection-based `equals` implementation. That sounds like a perfect recipe for a performance nightmare, including the possibility that the operation indeed takes hours to complete.